# Proper way of UITextField becoming firstResponder in an UITableViewCella after swipe

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` with some cells which have one `UITextField` each. After swiping on a row and pressing the swipe button I want to have the `UITextField` of the respective cell become the first responder in order to have the keyboard open immediately.

I implemented `editActionsForRow` with an `UITableViewRowAction`that looks like this

```swift
    UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: NSLocalizedString("Failed", comment: String())) { (_, indexPath) in
          if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ExerciseSetTableViewCell {
              if cell as? AnotherCell != nil {
              } else {
                 cell.titleTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true // Dont forget to disable!
                 cell.titleTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
              }
          }
```

*This does not work properly anymore since iOS 13*. The TextField becomes first responder and after like 1 second magically resigns first responder which causes the keyboard to close again. Also the entire cell gets hidden from the UI.

[broken animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgrYF.jpg)

**I already found a workaround:** If I delay the execution of `becomeFirstResponder` by the opening animation of the swipe gesture animation on the cell, the textField correctly does not resignFirstResponder.

[dirty workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krkPi.jpg)

This is quite dirty though and I am wondering what would be the proper way in doing that.

**Side note:** I already discovered by getting many layout warnings that calling `cellForRow` in an `UITableView` callback is a no-no. Still unsure how I would approach this here as I have to find the correct cell for the `indexPath`.

Comment: I have the same problem! It was working in iOS 12 but iOS 13 broke it. I've tried some hacks and nothing that works reliably. Let me know if you've found something!

Comment: Just fyi I did not get this to work, I rewrote my user interaction on the tableviewcell instead and no longer use swipe here. :/